# Sorting in C# using linq

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, sorting

When the Button Click I need to check   list is not orderby ascending  and dscending when page load. but I need to check  if the list is already ordered by ascending I need to ordered by descending , if the list is already ordered by descending need to ordered by ascending. how can I achieve this, I have attahced my code below. can anyone please help me on this??..

```
 public ActionResult OrderbyName(ResultWrapper wrapper)
 {
      wrapper.HotelDetails = wrapper.HotelDetails.OrderBy(m =>m.Name).ToList();
      //wrapper.HotelDetails = wrapper.HotelDetails.OrderByDescending(m => m.Name).ToList();
      //}
      //else
      //{
      //    wrapper.HotelDetails = wrapper.HotelDetails.OrderByDescending(m => m.Name).ToList();
      //}
      return Json(wrapper);
 }
```

Comment: Please break the question into several short and clear sentences. It didn't pass my parser so I don't know what you are asking.

Comment: Which type is `HotelWrapper.HotelDetails` - IEnumerable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (wrapper.HotelDetails.SequenceEqual(wrapper.HotelDetails.OrderBy(m => m.Name)))
{
    wrapper.HotelDetails = wrapper.HotelDetails.OrderByDescending(m => m.Name);
}
else if (wrapper.HotelDetails.SequenceEqual(wrapper.HotelDetails.OrderByDescending(m => m.Name)))
{
    wrapper.HotelDetails = wrapper.HotelDetails.OrderBy(m => m.Name);
}
else
{
    // List isn't ordered, you haven't specified what must be done in this case
}
```

First of all check if the sequence matches the ascending ordered version of itself, if so order it descending. If it matches the descending ordered version of itself order it ascending. If it's not ordered, you can do either, but you haven't specified this yet (unless I've misunderstood the question).

NOTE: This can be refactored to be more 'elegant' but I've left it as a simple, readable `if` statement so you can get the jist of what it's doing.

Comment: Please note that SequenceEqual enumerates the entire sequence; depending on the length of the sequence this could be quite slow.

Comment: @ShellShock - it's true. Whether this is an issue or not depends on OPs data set. If it is an issue, this article discusses a feasible alternative: http://www.dotnetperls.com/sequenceequal

Answer (score 1):

You could just do

```
wrapper.HotelDetails.Reverse()

return Json(wrapper.HotelDetails)
```

which will reverse the current order of the items.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question depends highly on additional information. If you are doing this inside a [DataGrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datagrid(v=vs.110).aspx), the answer may be "set `AllowSorting` to `true`".